# How to configure springboot to wrap DataSource during integration tests?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

My goal is to have a have integration tests that ensures that there isn't too many database queries happening during lookups.  (This helps us catch n+1 queries due to incorrect JPA configuration)

I know that the database connection is correct because there is no configuration problems during the test run whenever `MyDataSourceWrapperConfiguration` is not included in the test.  However, once it is added, the circular dependency happens. (see error below)  I believe `@Primary` is necessary in order for the JPA/JDBC code to use the correct `DataSource` instance.

`MyDataSourceWrapper` is a custom class that tracks the number of queries that have happened for a given transaction, but it delegates the real database work to the `DataSource` passed in via constructor.

Error:

```
The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration
┌─────┐
|  databaseQueryCounterProxyDataSource defined in me.testsupport.database.MyDataSourceWrapperConfiguration 
↑     ↓
|  dataSource defined in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat
↑     ↓
|  dataSourceInitializer
└─────┘
```

My Configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class MyDataSourceWrapperConfiguration {

    @Primary
    @Bean
    DataSource databaseQueryCounterProxyDataSource(final DataSource delegate) {
        return MyDataSourceWrapper(delegate);
    }
}
```

My Test:

```
@ActiveProfiles({ "it" })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration({ DatabaseConnectionConfiguration.class, DatabaseQueryCounterConfiguration.class })
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class EngApplicationRepositoryIT {

    @Rule
    public MyDatabaseQueryCounter databaseQueryCounter = new MyDatabaseQueryCounter ();

    @Rule
    public ErrorCollector errorCollector = new ErrorCollector();

    @Autowired
    MyRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        this.repository.loadData();
        this.errorCollector.checkThat(this.databaseQueryCounter.getSelectCounts(), is(lessThan(10)));
    }

}
```

**UPDATE: This original question was for springboot 1.5.  The accepted answer reflects that, however, the answer from @rajadilipkolli works for springboot 2.x**

Comment: You might be interested in https://vladmihalcea.com/2014/02/01/how-to-detect-the-n-plus-one-query-problem-during-testing/ (which actually uses a library to do so). To wrap your datasource I suggest to use a `BeanPostProcessor` which wraps the original `DataSource` in the proxied class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case you will get 2 `DataSource` instances which is probably not what you want. Instead use `BeanPostProcessor` which is the component actually designed for this. See also the [Spring Reference Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-extension-bpp).

Create and register a `BeanPostProcessor` which does the wrapping.

```
public class DataSourceWrapper implements BeanPostProcessor {

    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) {
        if (bean instanceof DataSource) {
             return new MyDataSourceWrapper((DataSource)bean);
        }
        return bean;
    }

    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Then just register that as a `@Bean` instead of your `MyDataSourceWrapper`.

**Tip:** Instead of rolling your own wrapping `DataSource` you might be interested in [datasource-proxy](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-extension-bpp) combined with [datasource-assert](https://github.com/ttddyy/datasource-assert) which has counter etc. support already (saves you maintaining your own components).

Comment: That was it.  `BeanPostProcessor` was the key.  Thank you for the recommendation of `datasource-assert`, I am using that, but left it out for the simplicity of the example.  However, it is good to mention it here for anyone else.  Thanks!  (Minor note, your example should be `instanceof`)

Comment: Fixed... (That was actually a result of auto-correct kicking in :) ).

Comment: This is breaking in spring-boot 2.0.0.M3, it used to work til 2.0.0.M2

Comment: wow! thank you for introducing me to `BeanPostProcessor` - this guy is a legend :)

Answer (score 4):

Starting from spring boot 2.0.0.M3 using BeanPostProcessor wont work.

As a work around create your own bean like below

```
  @Bean
    public DataSource customDataSource(DataSourceProperties properties) {
        log.info("Inside Proxy Creation");

        final HikariDataSource dataSource = (HikariDataSource) properties
                .initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
        if (properties.getName() != null) {
            dataSource.setPoolName(properties.getName());
        }
        return ProxyDataSourceBuilder.create(dataSource).countQuery().name("MyDS")
                .logSlowQueryToSysOut(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build();
    }
```

Another way is to use datasource-proxy version of [datasource-decorator](https://github.com/gavlyukovskiy/spring-boot-data-source-decorator) starter

Comment: Just pointing out that once we upgraded to springboot 2.x, this solution worked.

Answer (score 3):

Following solution works for me using Spring Boot 2.0.6.

It uses explicit binding instead of annotation `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.hikari")`.

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    private final Environment env;

    @Autowired
    public DataSourceConfig(Environment env) {
        this.env = env;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public MyDataSourceWrapper primaryDataSource(DataSourceProperties properties) {
        DataSource dataSource = properties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
        Binder binder = Binder.get(env);
        binder.bind("spring.datasource.hikari", Bindable.ofInstance(dataSource).withExistingValue(dataSource));
        return new MyDataSourceWrapper(dataSource);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually still use BeanPostProcessor in Spring Boot 2, but it needs to return the correct type (the actual type of the declared Bean). To do this you need to create a proxy of the correct type which redirects DataSource methods to your interceptor and all the other methods to the original bean.

For example code see the Spring Boot issue and discussion at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12592.

Comment: Saved my day :)

Comment: For information: Using Spring Boot 2.5 I have no problem returning different `DataSource` type from my `BeanPostProcessor` so I do not have to resort to proxying. It could very well be that the limitation you experienced was only true during the early days of Spring Boot 2.0 ?